# Get information from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 2 tables:

Table 1

```
Organization Location
001          110 
001          112
001          113
002          119
002          121
```

Table 2

```
 UserId    Location
 User1      110
 User1      112
 User2      121
```

My parameters are Organization and UserId. Table 2 is a table that restricts access. For example, for User1, he can only see info for Location 110 and 112.
User2 can only see information for location 121.

NOTE:
User3 which is not in table 2 can see info for all locations for a given Organization.So for example, for Organization 001 user 3 can see information for Location 110, 112, 113. Also note that any users that are not in table 2 are no restricted so we see all the locations for a given location.

How do I do a single select statement where the parameters are Organization and UserId. Based on that query I like to return the Location. I know a join is required but not sure how to construct it to accomplish the goal.

As I am entering this into a SelectCommand in ASP.NET SQLSource, I cannot use IF statement. I need to use a single select statement. I am using SQL Server for the database.

Comment: dynamic SQL is the solution :)

Comment: I voted down your question, because you don't know functionality of tools what you are gonna use. For example, in SQLSource SelectCommand you may execute stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could use the query like so:

```
select distinct t2.location
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 
  on t2.location = t1.location
  and '001' = t1.organization
  and t2.userid = 'User1'
```

For a given '001' organization and 'User1', you would get the location by joining the two tables on their common Location field.

This query can also be written as:

```
select distinct t2.location
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 
  on t2.location = t1.location
where 
  t1.organization = '001'
  and t2.userid = 'User1'
```

EDIT:

Stored procedure is likely to help you here:

```
delimiter //

drop procedure if exists get_locations//

create procedure get_locations (
    p_organization char(3),
    p_userid varchar(20)
)
begin

    -- find if there are any users corresponding
    -- to the user provided as an argument
    -- (see notes about org 001 and user2 below)
    select count(*) into @count_user
    from table2 where userid = p_userid;

    -- if org 001 and user User2 are provided, can they see
    -- all locations for 001? If the answer is yes, use the
    -- query below (commented) instead of the one above
    /*
    select count(*) into @count_user
    from table2 t2
    inner join table1 t1 on t1.location = t2.location
    where 
      t1.organization = p_organization 
      and t2.userid = p_userid;
    */

    -- if no user is found, show all location for that org
    if @count_user = 0 then
        select distinct location
        from table1
        where organization = p_organization;

    -- otherwise, get the right location for org and user
    else
        select distinct t1.location
        from table2 t2
        inner join table1 t1 on t1.location = t2.location
        where
            t1.organization = p_organization
            and t2.userid = p_userid;
    end if;

end//

delimiter ;
```

Results:

```
call get_locations('001','User1');
+----------+
| location |
+----------+
|      110 |
|      112 |
+----------+

call get_locations('001','User2');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

call get_locations('001','User3');
+----------+
| location |
+----------+
|      110 |
|      112 |
|      113 |
+----------+
```

EDIT 2: Using only select statement:

```
select distinct t2.location
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 
  on t2.location = t1.location
where 
  t1.organization = '001'
  and t2.userid = 'User3'

union

select distinct t2.location
from table2 t2
where 0 = (
  select count(*)
  from table2
  where userid = 'User3'
);
```

Will result in all 3 locations

```
select distinct t2.location
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 
  on t2.location = t1.location
where 
  t1.organization = '001'
  and t2.userid = 'User1'

union

select distinct t2.location
from table2 t2
where 0 = (
  select count(*)
  from table2
  where userid = 'User1'
)
```

will result in 2 locations.

Comment: Thank you. But for User3 I cannot do the inner join as you mentioned as he is not in table 2 but still I need to show all the results for say organization 001.

Comment: I'll need a little help understanding the problem. If user3 is not in table2, how do we know a user exists? What about an non existent user100? Do you want user100 to show up as well? Can you update your question with expected output and based on that I can edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I updated it under the NOTE section. Thank you once again.

Comment: Ah, in that case a stored procedure will help you

Comment: Anyway you can suggest a single SELECT statement to do what I need to do. That would really help vs creating a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Okay, I'll add a pure SELECT

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simple `union`:

```
select top 1 with ties from 
    (select t1.location, 1 as level
     from table1 t1
     join table2 on t1.location = t2.location
     where t2.userid = 'user' and t1.organization = '001'

     union all

     select location, 2 as level
     from table1
     where organization = '001') t
order by level
```

If restrictions table holds some rows for user it will select only those rows. Else it will select all locations from `table1`.